# how to add control charecter CR to the end of line in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

How can I add control character CR with notepad ++ to the end of all lines in ones. File containing informations such pictures graphs videos.There are two control character CR and LF in the file that I work but CR is missing at the end of each line and I have thousands of lines.

Answer (score 2):

Go into Notepad++.  Hit Control F for Find.  Click on the Replace tab at the top.  In the Find what: area type '\r' which represents CR. (without the single quotes) Go down to the Replace with area and type '\r\n' which represents CR LN (without the single quotes). Go down to the Search Mode and click on Extended radio button and turn this on.  After this make sure you are at the top of the file with your cursor by clicking in the very top left of the corner.  Now click replace all.  This should do it.  Now save.

Comment: I see.  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Replace, {search mode: rule based expression} search for \r replace with \r\n

\r is cr
\n is lf

You might want to control what's happening by viewing all control codes:

View, [View symbol], [All characters]

Also you might want to start easy by searching and replacing in two operations, one occurrence at the time.

Comment: can not added with replace option

Comment: yes cant add control character with replace option

Comment: Edit -> Character Panel

Comment: You're better off getting hold of the original file where at least LF is present so that you can do a bulk replace.

Comment: Edit -> Character Panel -> [set cursor at the insert point] -> [double click the character you want from the list]

Comment: yes I already tried this but the problem I have 114913 lines :)

Comment: That's what I thought and that's why I suggest you get hold of the original which must at least offer LF to search for which in turn can be replaced with CRLF. If you got nothing to search for at the point where you want to insert your code, how can a computer, which only do as we say, figure out where you want all your codes? Do you want a computer with artificial intelligence - is that what you're here for?

Comment: agree with you but with control F I already tried this, but it doesn't make any changes for control characters but for all other informations I can change, replace etc. I don't know if I a m clear

Comment: It will replace all occurrence of LF to CRLF if your follow my instruction in my first answer. Before you try this you would want to show all the control codes in the file. This you do by [View] - > [View symbols] -> [All characters]. BTW, are you sure you're reading me well?

Comment: sure I do, and appreciate for your help.is there any way to attach the file for you

Comment: Good idea. No, no uploading at this site. Send the file to me by email, frank.lillesand@gmail.com or use a file uploading service and post the link.

Comment: I send it with the title of --hi from super user

Comment: Now, did you get the gif pictures?

Comment: it work, CR added before LF thank you very much Frank , really appreciate for your help. but still I cant transfer to the program. maybe there are other small corrections needed I don't know .but ones again thanks a lot

Comment: At least you have learnt how to edit files at the binary level. It can come in handy one day - we never know. I must say it's kind of odd that an updated program is unable to read its own file formats from an earlier version. Are you sure you are doing this as you supposed to do. Have you looked for an import function in the newest program, or maybe even a file coverter floating around. It felt like a long shot to edit in just CR which is in fact redundant and adds no complexity to the file.